# Updating 2 tables in one Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

Please have a look at the below trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Transactions_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` 
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Portfolio 
    SET Invest_Amount = Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount
    WHERE idPortfolio = NEW.idPortfolio
```

In my `Transactions` table, there is another field called `Balance`. It is equal to `Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount` as well. So, how can I update this column as well, in the same Trigger?

Comment: You may have to change from `AFTER INSERT` to a `BEFORE INSERT` to get what you need. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fc07/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work, although I admit I have never tried this in a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Transactions_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` 
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Portfolio , Balance
    SET Portfolio.Invest_Amount = Portfolio.Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount,
Balance.Invest_Amount = Balance.Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount
    WHERE Portfolio.idPortfolio = NEW.idPortfolio and Balance.idPortfolio = NEW.idPortfolio
```

Answer (score 0):

Use begin and end keywords to do more statements within the same trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Transactions_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Portfolio 
        SET Invest_Amount = Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount
        WHERE idPortfolio = NEW.idPortfolio;
        UPDATE Transactions t SET Balance =
             (SELECT Invest_Amount FROM Portfolio WHERE idPortfolio = t.idPortFolio)
        WHERE idTransactions = NEW.idTransactions;
    END; $$
```

Comment: OK, but what is the other statement?

Comment: seems to be..pls give me a minute.

Comment: Perhaps idTransactions doesn't exist? It was a pure guess that it would exist.

Comment: The trigger is generating the following error: `Can't update table 'transactions' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`